# Ways of impersonation c# ws2008

Tags: c#

I want to run application under ws2008 in the context of different user. I use System.Diagnostic.Process with user, password and domain. When I use this method and user belongs only to iis_iusrs group I get "The directory is invalid" message.

When I run runas command from cmd auth as a user I can run application.

Is there other way to run application in context of other user ?

Comment: What kind of application is that? Is it an interactive application trying to display a window? Is the application accessing folders in the context of that user (e.g. user's temp folder, app data folder etc)?

Comment: It is command line application, I think that there is no problem with application because I tried to run a few from different locations (c:\ , c:\windows\ etc.)

Comment: Command line app sounds already good. Is that app accessing the temp folder? Do you maybe get a more detailed error message telling you which directory is "invalid"?

Comment: Well I think that it is some kind of generic error message. I tried to run in the same way different app from different location and I got the same message

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because iis_iusrs does not have any access rights to a directory you are starting your app from.